# Excel Find operation in C# will skip the first row

Tags: c#, excel-interop

Below is a working code. I figured out that in the find criteria that by changing the starting point of the search criteria as: wsSheet.Cells[65000, columnNumber] it will solve the issue. This is not a real solution though.

Is there another way of forcing the Find operation to start at the first row of the excel sheet?

```
public static string FindFirstStringInColumn(Excel.Workbook wbBook, string strSheet, string strSearchMe, string strColumnLetter)

    {
        Excel.Worksheet wsSheet = null;
        wsSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wbBook.Worksheets[strSheet];
        Excel.Range currentFind = null;


        Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)wsSheet.Columns[strColumnLetter, Type.Missing];
        int columnNumber = ExcelCOM.GetColumnNumber(strColumnLetter);
        //~~> Search for strSearchMe
        currentFind = range.Find(strSearchMe,
                        wsSheet.Cells[65000, columnNumber],
                        Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                        Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                        Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                        Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                        false,
                        false,
                        false);

        if (currentFind != null)
        {
            string sAddress = currentFind.get_Address(false, false, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, false, false);
            //~~> Display the found Address
            return (sAddress).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return ("Nothing found");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am thinking about the Excel functions where you specify a range to be sorted, and it prompts you for whether the column names are in the first row...

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been able to gather, try specifying

`range.Cells[range.Count]`

as your "After" parameter value, which at least gets rid of the hardcoded 65000, and should work correctly for ranges other than entire columns.

Answer (score 0):

That parameter is optional, use named parameters and don't specify it, this should start with the "top most" cell in the range.

Comment: Are you sure? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find(v=office.11).aspx) states "If you don’t specify this argument, the search starts **after** the cell in the upper-left corner of the range."

Comment: But it will wrap -- You're answer is better if you want the upper left to be the first result and not the last.